# How to Use The IPs Of Remote Linux server as The Additional IPs of My Current Linux Server?

Tags: centos, linux-networking, tunneling

I have 2 Linux Servers 'X' and 'Y'.

Server X has lots of resources but 2 public IPs (1 main IP bound as eth0 and 1 additional IP bound as eth0:0).

Server Y has 9 public IPs (1 main IP bound as eth0 and 8 additional IPs bound as eth0:0 to eth0:7) but a limited amount of resources.

### I want to use server Y additional IPs (8 IPs) on server X so that server X will have 10 IPs total.

I googled around and I think it's possible to do so using IPIP tunnels/GRE tunnels I've been trying for a few days but so far no luck.

### Here's what I've been doing on both servers:

**Server X**

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0;
ip tunnel add tunx mode gre remote |Y's Main IP| local |X's Main IP| ttl 255 dev eth0;
ip link set tunx up;
ip addr add 10.10.1.1/32 dev tunx peer 10.10.1.2;
ip addr add |One of Y's Additional IPs|/29 dev eth0;
```

**Server Y**

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0;
ip tunnel add tuny mode gre remote |X's Main IP| local |Y's Main IP| ttl 255 dev eth0;
ip link set tuny up;
ip addr add 10.10.1.2/32 dev tuny;
ip route add |Y's first additional IP|/29 via 10.10.1.2;
```

After the above commands on both servers when I try the following command from X:

```
traceroute -s|One of Y's additional IPs| google.com

I get this:

traceroute to google.com (173.194.70.113), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
```

Answer (score 2):

At least two errors are in your setup:

1. ServerX needs routing rules to forward traffic from Y1 to the tunnel.
2. tuny on ServerY needs a peer address.

Also use /32 routes and masks for migrated addresses to prevent routing loops.

Let:

1. ServerX main IP = X
2. ServerY main IP = Y
3. ServerY additional IP = Y1

Then the following I believe is closer to working config:

**ServerX:**

```
...
ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre remote Y local X ttl 255
ip link   set tun0 up

ip addr add Y1/32 dev eth0
ip addr add 10.10.1.1 dev tun0 peer 10.10.1.2

ip route  add default via 10.10.1.2 dev tun0 table 100
ip rule   add from  Y1 table 100
```

**ServerY**

```
ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre remote X local Y ttl 255
ip link   set tun0 up

ip addr add 10.10.1.2 dev tun0 peer 10.10.1.1

ip route add Y1/32 via 10.10.1.1 dev tun0
```

You may also consider alternative setup with single GRE tunnel and static NAT on ServerY to make IP addresses on ServerY available for services on ServerX.

**UPD:**

I just checked this. It seems to be working.

Relevant iptables config to allow traffic flows:

**ServerY:**

```
-A FORWARD -d Y1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s Y1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
```

**ServerX:**

```
-A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
```

Problems can be debugged in the following order:

1. Be sure that X and Y are reachable.
2. Be sure that the tunnel is up and working: `ping <tunnel-peer-address>`.
3. If not, check if providers allow GRE traffic.
4. Track how icmp packets are processed: `tcpdump -i tun0 icmp` and `tcpdump -i eth0 icmp`.

**Good book is "Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO".**

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply,
I tried the suggested configuration above but it didn't work.

Is it possible that ISP has reverse path filtering ?
How can I check and is there any work around it ?

Any help is appreciated I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

Comment: Also can you please explain the other method using (SNAT)?

One last thing is there a good book where I can learn more about all the linux networking stuff ?

Once again thanks!

Comment: I have updated with further useful info. This setup is simpler to debug then one with NAT. And you can still use single tunnel for all forwarded addresses.

Comment: I know it has been a while I did the exact same steps above but no luck when I connect to Y1 from server Y it connects to server X correctly buy when I try to ping Y1 from any other network it doesn't work any idea what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the configuration of IP addresses from server Y and add them to the configuration of server X (so you only have one server with a specific IP address)?

Comment: Each server is hosted by a diff. ISP